Push-pull converter primary RMS current calculation
I would like to calculate the RMS value of the primary current for a CCM mode Push-Pull converter. If I am correct, this is equal to the current through the switching elements (e.g., NFETs). I have tried to determine the RMS value, and my question is whether this is correct. Additionally, I believe I only need to consider one switching period in my calculations. Here are my calculations:



